# Numbers with leading zeros in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, xml

I receive a long XML from backend. To further use the xml I convert it to JSON object using one of the standard XMLtoJSON javascript library. The issue is, some of the XML value contains number with leading zeros eg: 001072.

The problem is, when javascript library converts xml to JSON, number with leading zeros give completely different value.

For example

> “001072” converts “570”

Other times it parse it correctly. For example:

> “0045678” converts to 45678

The problem is how javascript handle number with zeros. I don’t know the reason of this strange behavior!!

Please suggest a solution which can parse number with zeros consistently and how can I use it with xmltojson library

Comment: i know it's evasive solution but you can use string slicing until you find the real problem that leads such anomaly

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a problem with [octal literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Integers). If a number starts with a leading 0, JavaScript by default will try to parse it as an octal literal.

For this reason, you should always specify the radix parameter when calling `parseInt`. The library probably does not do that.

```
parseInt("012", 8); // 10
parseInt("012", 10); // 12
```

I think [this](https://github.com/metatribal/xmlToJSON/blob/master/lib/xmlToJSON.js#L53) is the offending line in the library, probably. Either edit the library, or edit your XML.

Answer (score 0):

Octal numbers with the leading zero are on the way out. For ECMAScript5 they can still cause problems and are thus not allowed in `strict mode` and throw a runtime error. You really should not be using 3rd party scripts that are not in strict mode they are dangerous for way too many reasons, as you can see with the handling of the octal numbers.

As ECMAScript 6 becomes more wide spread the use of the leading zero will be pushed out all together.

Octals literals will have a '0o' prefix `0o10 === 8` can be uppercase 'o' but I am sure you can see this will be a hassle. ES6 will also formalise the binary format with the prefix `0b1000 === 8` though most browsers have supported it for some time. Hex has also been around for a while `0x08 == 8`

The reason some numbers with leading zeros are decmil and some octal is dependent on what digits are in the number. Octal does not use the digits 8 and 9 so any number that have these digits can not be octal.